# Displaying all the days of a month 

Tags: android, date, drop-down-menu

In my application,  when the user selects to view the details of the current month, a new screen will open. In that screen, we will have a drop down menu. In the drop down menu I want to display all the dates of that month. So that he can select the date he is interested in.

For example, if the current month is Feb, then drop down menu is expected to contain 28 numbers( sometimes 29).

I have used xml layout in my app.

Could anyone suggest me a better way of implementing this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DatePicker...

here is the sample code..

Write this in your activity class..

```
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth,
                    cday);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        // onDateSet method
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) { 
            String date_selected = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + " - "
                    + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1) + " - "
                    + String.valueOf(year);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Date is =" +   date_selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
```

and call this whenever you want to display the Datepicker..

```
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

That displays a nice DatePicker from which you can select a date....

Answer (score 0):

Use [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) widget, here is the [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)