# How to get current day (trimmed to 3 char only) in angular2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-pipe

Have used `currentDate = new Date();` in my `typescript file` and tried to render by using `{{currentDate}}` but it shows full format like `Sun Aug 06 2017 15:36:11 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

I took reference from [AngularDatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) , then i render `{{currentDate | date}}` now it shows like `Aug 6, 2017` .  **But what i want is just day with starting 3 char only** like **Sun , Sat .. and so** is there any way to *retrieve* it from this format `Sun Aug 06 2017 15:36:11 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

Comment: *I took reference from `AngularDatePipe`* Is there some reason you did not actually read that page, which could not describe the `EEE` option any more clearly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the short form ": EEE" after the date pipe.

```
{{currentDate | date : 'EEE'}}
```

Check this link for different formats [date filter](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 1):

{{ today | date : "EEE" }}

EEE should give you a three letter day

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `EEE`

```
     <p>{{today | date:'EEE'}}</p>
```

Use the method as per this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146418/find-all-the-days-in-a-month-with-date-object) and use that array in the DOM.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fLpWwrE8IY6kfAeu32hC?p=preview)**

Comment: it works , any way to __get all dates and corresponding day__ for specific month like for august.?