# how to enable two day only in react-day-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I need to enable two days only in my `react-day-picker`. The remaining days should be disabled. Could anyone give me an example of how to accomplish this?

I tried with [this example](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/disabled) but it not working for me.

```
export default function Example() {
  getDaysInMonth(month, year){
    // Since no month has fewer than 28 days
    let date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    const days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
      dateys.push(new Date(date));
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
  }
  const disabledMonth = this.getDaysInMonth(12, 2017);
    return (
      <DayPicker
        initialMonth={new Date(2017, 3)}
        disabledDays={
          this.disabledMonth.filter(
            (date) => ![new Date(2017, 12, 3), new Date(2017, 12, 13)].includes(date)
          )
        }
      />
    );
}
```

i tried to run this code i getting empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is that you could set [that the user should not be able to change the month](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker#canChangeMonth) if the two days are within the same month. You can set which month this is with [initial month](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker#initialMonth).

You can then set the [disabled days](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker#disabledDays) which will be an array of dates which is the days of that month excluding the two available days.

Example:

If you use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13146828/2246084) to have a method to get all dates in a month, you could do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import DayPicker from 'react-day-picker';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

export default function Example() {
  const disabledMonth = getDaysInMonth(11, 2017);

  return (
    <DayPicker
      initialMonth={new Date(2017, 11)}
      disabledDays={
        this.disabledMonth.filter(
          (date) => ![new Date(2017, 11, 3).toString(), new Date(2017, 11, 13).toString()].includes(date.toString())
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Here i am filtering out two dates, the 3rd and 13th of december, which should be available.

This is written with es6

Comment: Thank for your quick reply @madshvero i am using that component only can u give me some example for this

Comment: I had edit the code above, still, i am getting the array is empty can check the code resolve it

Comment: @sedhuraghuraman I am not sure what you mean. Where is the array empty? What have you tried?

Comment: i try to print the `disabledMonth` in console i getting empty array only

Comment: Did you include the function I'm referring to? `getDaysInMonth`

Comment: i rewrite the code at top can check and tell me what is the problem, I am trying to fix but i cant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161211/discussion-between-madshvero-and-sedhuraghuraman).