# How to add present month dates as Headers for each individual column in html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Am unsatified with the other answers with realted question asked by me. i want each column header of a `html` to be displayed with a individual date when web page is loaded to that specific month in `javascript`. I tried but i got no success. Here is my javascript code.

```
function addRows(table, dates) {
        var idx = 1;
        for (var i in dates) {
            table.append(
                         '<th><input name="date'+idx+'" id="date'+idx+'" class="date" value="'+dates[i]+'"></th>'
             );
            idx++;
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        var myDate = new Date();
        var year   = myDate.getFullYear();
        var month  = myDate.getMonth(); 
        var dates  = myDate.daysInMonth(year, month);
        var table  = $("#myTable").find("tbody");
        addRows(table, dates);
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

link below will show you the code to create an array wit each date in it.

[Find all the days in a month with Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146418/find-all-the-days-in-a-month-with-date-object)

you could then map over the array creating a table header for each item in the array

Comment: Thanks for the link Mr. Steve Bohmbach. The problem is am able to get the dates according to the specific month and am able to display vertically but i want to set each individual day date Horizontally in a table like excel dates,  to individual column header i.e' in <th> of a table header. Can you Help me Out please ?

Comment: @Naim are you encasing the <th> items in a <tr> tag?

Comment: Yes Mr steve, and am encasing <th>  within <tr>.

Comment: How do i append those dates in each individual <th> on top of the table ?? i hope my problem will be solved.